# Iteration in Python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iteration

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s="aaabbc"
>>> import itertools
>>> gs=itertools.groupby(s)
>>> for key, group in gs:
...   print(key, group)
...   print(list(group))
...   print(key, group, list(group))
... 
a <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd246da3278>
['a', 'a', 'a']
a <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd246da3278> []
b <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd246da32e8>
['b', 'b']
b <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd246da32e8> []
c <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd246da39b0>
['c']
c <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fd246da39b0> []
```

As the code showed, there is something amazing in above for-loop:in one iteration, the key and the itertools._groupre object didn't change, however the results of list(group) changed.Exactly, the 2nd list(group) got None. I just can't find out why. WHY? (My English isn't so good, I hope you can understand what I asked)

Comment: Generators can only produce their values *once*. You don't get `None`, you get an empty list because the `group` generator has been exhausted by the first `list()` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generators can only be iterated over *once*. Each `group` in the `groupby()` result is such a generator. Calling `list()` on a generator causes it to yield all values, after which the generator is *exhausted*, empty, and can not be reset; a second `list()` call on the same object then simply results in an empty list, since the generator no longer yields values to put in the list.

Store the result of `list()` in a new variable instead:

```
for key, group in gs:
    group_result = list(group)
    print(key, group)
    print(group_result)
    print(key, group, group_result)
```

Now you call `list()` on the generator just the once, and reuse the result.

Comment: Okay，it's a generator. I got it. I know that the generator can only be iterated over once, but I didn't find out that group was a generator. I'll be careful with generator from now on. Thank you~